# LoginForm in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

please, how can I add LoginForm to MasterPage? I Added LoginForm Control to MasterPage, but when I try click to another button, Validators in LoginForm show alerts... How Can I fix it please? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Master Page is not generally the place for a login form. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

If you want a user to be able to login from any page that inherits from that master then I would put the login in .ascx control and drop that on the page. You should then be certain to add the tag "validationGroup" to those controls. (see Validation Grouping on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.aspx)

Cheers, 
CEC

Comment: Thank you, now I'm going read about User Controls and I'll give feedback tomorrow. :)

Comment: as you read up on User Controls (good start) also pay attention to Validation Groups, they are an important part of getting the results I believe you are after.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to putting your login control into a user control, on the "other buttons" you click, you also need to set the property CausesValidation="False" if they aren't intended to trigger validation.